# Map IQueryable<Entity> to IQueryable<DTO> in Linq with nested objects

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, automapper, asp.net-web-api, dto

I'm trying to map IQueryable< entity> to IQueryable< entityDTO> using Automapper for generating Linq.  I'm working on a Web API project w/ entity framework and oracle 11g.

```
public virtual IQueryable<TDto> Get() 
{
IQueryable<TEntity> EntObjs;
EntObjs = GenericService.Get();     
var Dtos = EntObjs.Project().To<TDto>();
return Dtos;
}
```

It works fine as long as the Tentity type does not have any Collections in it. I found info at http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/stop-using-automapper-in-your-data-access-code that has got be halfway to solving the problem. I know I can map the collections with Automapper using the follow function, but I need it to be in linq so I do not break the Iquerable chain.

```
Mapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>(Source,Destincation);
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>You may use this in the query chain.</s>

For example:

```
EntObjs.Project(). Select(x=> Mapper.Map(x))...
```

Comment: Does the Mapper.Map break the IQueryable chain? I cant break this chain due to using Odata filters.

Comment: Sorry it might. Try it out and let me know.